# open-quote is positioned incorrectly in Firefox 18 using :before and content

Tags: css

I am using `:before` to insert the `content` element `open-quote`.

[image: Screenshot open-quote]

The CSS Code:

```
blockquote {
    background:#f9f9f9;
    color: #555;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left:5px solid #ccc;
    margin:0 30px;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7),-5px -4px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
blockquote:before {
    color:#ccc;
    content:open-quote;
    font-size:4em;
    float:left;
    margin-top:-30px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #909090;
}
```

With Chrome and IE9 it seems to work without any issue.

I guess `margin-top:-30px;` gets interpreted differently by Firefox.

How can I solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I can solve this by using a css browser hack:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
    blockquote:before {
        margin-top:0;
    }
}
```

But I would be glad to get a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

My version of Firefox doesn't seem to display that behavior.  Relative positioning is another option:

http://jsfiddle.net/3WMwt/

```
blockquote:before {
    color:#ccc;
    content:open-quote;
    font-size:4em;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    top:-30px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #909090;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. I have no idea why it does not work on my (website)[http://www.echteinfach.tv/] (scroll down a bit to see the box). I assume that there is some other CSS interfering. However, `blockquote` is not defined elsewhere in my CSS.